# Javascript - Benefit gained from sorting DOM collection

Tags: javascript, sorting, css-selectors

I am working on my personal project, which is to create a javascript selector engine. The engine would use CSS2 - CSS3 syntax to select element nodes. I was comparing my engine's selection results to other selector engines' results (mainly to Sizzle). I also compared it to native selector method called querySelectorAll (QSA). I noticed a one difference.

The HTML structure of the document is as simple as this:

`<code><span></span></code>`

The selector I used was:

> 'span, code'

When I performed the selection using Sizzle or QSA, the result I got was this:

`[<code>...</code>, <span></span>]`

When I used my selector engine, the result was this:

`[<span></span>, <code>...</code>]`

It appears to be, that Sizzle and QSA sort the collection according to the position of the element on the document. My selector engine doesn't do so. I found out, that sorting can be achieved using compareDocumentPosition and Array sort methods. Obviously this would affect to the performance a bit, although I haven't tested it yet. (source: http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/).

I am wondering if sorting nodes offer some benefits over the "non-sorted" nodes. For example, is it more efficient to add css styles to the nodes of the collection (in a loop, ie.), when elements are sorted. Are there other cases, where it might be better to use sorted collection?

Example (elementNodes contains the selection results):

> for (var i = 0, il = elementNodes.length; i < il; i++) {
>
> ```
>  elementNodes[i].style.height = '100px';
>
>  elementNodes[i].style.width = '100px';
>
>  elementNodes[i].style.background = 'red';
> ```
>
> }

Comment: I believe the only advantage to be gained by sorting the nodes is predictability, which isn't to be sniffed at...

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Source code of what? The method to sort element collection can be found from the link I gave (it's a post from John Resig's awesome blog) and I am too shamed to show code from my selector engine :D I'm not too good at writing beautiful code.

Comment: Well, you're saying that you have some code to select faster than QSA or Sizzle, I want to see that :-). If it's too bad, maybe make it good? It would only be good for you :-)

Comment: My selector engine probably isn't as fast as QSA. It's faster than Sizzle (according to jsPerf), but mine has a lot more bugs and less features at the moment. I just started rewriting it, because I got a better idea how it should be done. Maybe I'll show it one day, when it's in better condition :P I am going to use it as a fallback, when QSA isn't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, i like what you are doing here and especially like that you are doing comparisons against other open source engines.

in reality both examples are "sorted" just differently.

unless you find a compelling reason (i can't think of one) to sort yours the same way as sizzle then don't do it.  as long as you understand the order of your own engine which you clearly do and others can also understand it then that is what matters most.